# How can i send request with proxy on axios?

Tags: axios, proxy, openssl

```
> Blockquote

AxiosError: write EPROTO 1C3B0000:error:0A00010B:SSL routines:ssl3_get_record:wrong version number:c:\ws\deps\openssl\openssl\ssl\record\ssl3_record.c:355:
```

I get this error when I try to send a request via proxy with Axios. I've searched the Internet, but I haven't been able to reach any results.

```
const axios = require('axios')

axios({
    url: 'https://medal.tv',
    method:'GET',
    proxy: {
        protocol: 'http',
        host: 'xxx',
        port: 3000,
        auth: { username: 'xxx', password: 'xxx' }
    },  
}).then(e => console.log(e.data)).catch(e => console.log(e))
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use proxy with Axios by using [https-proxy-agent](https://www.npmjs.com/package/https-proxy-agent) and Axios of course!

```js
  const axios = require('axios');
  var HttpsProxyAgent = require('https-proxy-agent');
  const axiosResponse = await axios.get(url, {
            headers: {
                'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/85.0.4183.83 Safari/537.36'
            },
            proxy: false,
            httpsAgent: new HttpsProxyAgent.HttpsProxyAgent(`https://username:password@host:port`)
        });
    }
```